# How to remove padding from all sides (including top and bottom) of a HorizontalBarChart (MPAndroidChart)?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create HorizontalBarChart that covers the entire parent layout (`LinearLayout` inside a `ConstraintLayout`).
Here is my code:

```
public static HorizontalBarChart horizontalBarChartSet(Context context, HorizontalBarChart mChart, float value) {
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    //Vertical Axis
    mChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);

    //Horizontal Axis 1
    YAxis yl = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    yl.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yl.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yl.setDrawLabels(false);
    yl.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    yl.setAxisMaximum(100f);

    //Horizontal Axis 2
    YAxis yr = mChart.getAxisRight();
    yr.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yr.setDrawLabels(false);
    yr.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    yr.setAxisMaximum(100f);

    //Data
    ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    values.add(new BarEntry(0, value));

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(values, "");

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set);

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    mChart.setData(data);

    //Highlight
    data.setHighlightEnabled(false);

    //Bar
    data.setBarWidth(0.8f);
    mChart.setFitBars(true);

    //Legend
    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    //General
    mChart.setViewPortOffsets(0f,0f,0f,0f);
    mChart.setExtraOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    //Animate
    mChart.animateY(2500);
    return mChart;
}
```

using `setViewPortOffsets(0f,0f,0f,0f);` though remove padding from left and right but there is still some padding on top and bottom and when I touch the bar the left and right padding also reverts to default values.

XML of the view:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here are screenshots:
Look at Food Item of ListView

[Before I touch the bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgiRj.png)

[After I touch the bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKMyG.png)

Comment: can you please share screenshots

Comment: you could use negative padding for designing your layout

Comment: @MehulKabaria I added the screenshots. See my edit.

Comment: @PranavAshok I've tried using `android:padding="-40dp"` but it changes nothing.

Comment: @MuhammadShahbaz: can you please explain what exactly you want.

Comment: @MehulKabaria as I mentioned in the question title I want to remove padding from all sides of a `HorizontalBarChart`.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try following

```
mChart.invalidate();
```

After you add `HorizontalBarChart` in data.

Comment: I tried using invalidate() method but it doesn't affect anything.